# Does Smartphone or Tab follow any specific pattern of their MAC address?

Tags: tablet, smartphone, mac-address

Can I get any information about the device, whether it is smartphone or tablet with the help of their MAC address. Suppose, I am getting a MAC address (C8:20:F9:89:8E:2F). How can I trace, that it is a **smartphone or tab** ? Does they follow any specific pattern ?